# PHP Assign Variable to Another Variable even if it is Null without giving Undefined notice

Tags: php

Ex : `<?php $name = $firstname; ?>`

I need to assign `$firstname` to `$name`. If `$firstname` is NULL `$name` should be a empty string without giving Undefined notice.

**I know that this can be easily done with a if condition with isset**, but I want to know that is there any single default function to this task without using if condition with isset?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: `$name = @$firstname;`

Comment: <?php
$firstname = "DAmith";
 $name = ($firstname == NULL) ? ' '; $firstname; ?>

Comment: @sunil `Undefined variable firstname` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: using @ should be avoided. rather just change log level to hide notices

Comment: @user2914191 Even worse! Don't write code that may throw notices, period. Don't hide them, not locally, not globally. Notices are there to alert you to (possible) problems, you *want* to see them!

Comment: @deceze not worse. applying @ to every variable is worse than hiding notices. you can unhide notices with ease.

Comment: @user Writing code which throws notices at all *is worse* than any alternative to suppress those notices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
$name = isset($firstname) ? $firstname : '';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the null coalescing operator:

```
$name = $firstname ?? "";
```

**PHP 7+ only.**